# .NET Core 6 CORS issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, http-get

I have a simple API and when I call my API from another website I get CORS error. I have tested everything and nothing seems to work. The request works fine in Postman. I have an API key middleware and I have attached the code for it also. The other thing is that I only get the CORS error, if I pass the API key in header. If I pass it as a query string, I don't get any errors or to be more precise, it gives me a 404 but it runs the code and returns the result anyways:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MY_API;
using MY_API.Data;
using MY_API.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Connection"));
});

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("corsPolicy",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy
                               .AllowAnyOrigin()
                               .AllowAnyMethod()
                               .AllowAnyHeader();

                      });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("corsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I am running a simple GET request.

```
// GET: api/Tests/5
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> GetTest(int id)
{
    var Test = await _context.Tests.FindAsync(id);

    if (Test == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Test;
}
```

My API key middleware is like this. Please note the commented line which I use to switch between passing in the headers or query string:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MY_API.Middleware
{
    public class ApiKeyMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private const string APIKEY = "apiKey";

        public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(APIKEY, out var extractedApiKey))
            //   if (!context.Request.Query.TryGetValue(APIKEY, out var extractedApiKey))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Api Key was not provided ");
                return;
            }

            var appSettings = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

            var apiKey = appSettings.GetValue<string>(APIKEY);

            if (!apiKey.Equals(extractedApiKey))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized client");
                return;
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get:

[image: Error]

If I pass the API as query string, I get something like this, but it returns the result. Please note it is for a different GET request and the name is different:

[image: Working one]

Comment: GET requests usually don't need to be same origin, so pre-flight doesn't care about origin for those.  It may want origin to be the same for any other verb or custom header... this helps prevent XSS/CSRF because it will force same-origin.  (or should anyway...)

Comment: so it's assumed that GET does not perform anything that is "state changing"... ex: update, insert, delete, or login...

Comment: btw, Postman doesn't care about cross-site requests... these CORS restrictions are built-in to modern browsers.  The CORS headers you are sending tell the browser to loosen it's restrictions, but Postman doesn't have any to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.
I had to allow options in IIS manager:

[image]